# Can CMS and ParNew run concurrently?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

Two questions about the CMS collector:

1. Will ParNew run concurrently with a CMS old gen collection.
2. In the GC log, I do not see the old gen usage after a CMS collection. How can I check how much space is collected in the old gen and how much still remains.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes - ParNew will run whilst CMS is performing one of its concurrent phases. This can lead to GC log corruption as the JVM's logging is not thread-safe with respect to the GC threads.
2. CMS performs a parallel sweep. While this is running, a ParNew can cause objects to be promoted to old gen. The question "how much memory was collected by CMS?" is therefore neither very useful or entirely meaningful.